# No ~/.vim folder in ubuntu 13.04 where to go for it

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I am trying to install different plug-ins in vim. I have installed vim using `sudo apt-get install vim`. But the downloaded files for these plug-ins need to be placed in ~/.vim folder. But there is no such folder. I've found a vim folder in /etc and also in /usr/share directories. Which one to use..??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can copy the plugins in the /etc/vim folder, if you want them to be available for all users:

```
sudo cp -rv /route/to/nameoftheplugin /etc/vim/
```

Or, if  you only need them for your use, just create the vim directory in your home:

```
mkdir ~/.vim
```

Then to open that folder, just type:

```
nautilus ~/.vim
```

Comment: I have copied the plugin files to /etc/vim. The plugin is snipmate. Now when I open a C file the plugin is not working.. :/

Comment: You should read the information about how that specific plugin works, maybe you need to unpack it, or give it executable permissions? The plugin should come with some kind of install information.

Answer (score 3):

Just create it,

```
mkdir ~/.vim
```

and then move the plug-in files to said folder.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the `.vim` folder in your home folder. All plugins will go into the `~/.vim/plugins` folder. Your personal initialization options will go into the `~/.vimrc` file.

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me:
open the vim editor and type `:echo $VIMRUNTIME`

in my case it was `/usr/share/vim/vim74`

Go to the `plugin` directory inside your runtime directory and copy your plugin file there.

I've copied `yaml.vim` for YAML syntax highlighting. Works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

The .vim folder can be found in your `Home` directory. The dot(.) at the beginning means the vim folder is hidden. Extract the plugins into the .vim folder for installing the vim plugins.